# How do I get the the index of a 2D array (jlabel) through mouselisteners in java?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, multidimensional-array, mouseclick-event

How can you get the index of a 2D array of JLabels with mouseclick listeners?

```
        for (x =  0; x < 8; x++) {
        for(y=0; y<8; y++){
            jLabel[x][y]=new javax.swing.JLabel(blank);


            jPanel1.add(jLabel[x][y]);

            jLabel[x][y].addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jLabelMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
       }
       y=0;

    }
```

---

```
private int jLabelMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    System.out.println("clicked");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Get the component using `evt.getSource()`
- Loop through the `jLabel` array until the source == the x & y co-ords

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I promise to give you an upvote when i get enough rep. :D

Comment: No worries.  Glad you got it sorted.  :)